# Error when using ActionChains.send_keys in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am coming across an error when using `actionchains.send_keys` (the last line of my code)

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import pyperclip

driver = wd.Chrome()

driver.get('https://temp-mail.org/en/') #opens the website
copy_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="click-to-copy"]') #Finds ID for copy button
copy_btn.click() #Clicks the copy button


driver.execute_script("window.open('');") #opens a new tab
time.sleep(3) #waits for tab to open
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]) #switches to the new tab

driver.get('https://google.com ') #opens the website
input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input') #Finds ID for search
ActionChains.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'v').perform() #Pastes the text that was previously copied
```

Error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/Shadow/PycharmProjects/untitled1/venv/Test.py", line 26, in <module>
>     ActionChains.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'v').perform()
>   File "C:\Users\Shadow\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\action_chains.py", line 336, in send_keys
>     if self._driver.w3c:
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_driver'
> ```

Code that causes the error:

```
ActionChains.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'v').perform() #Pastes the text that was previously copied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have better results by sending directly the sequence from the element :

```
input.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v').perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using clipboard for storing any data because your tests need to be [small, atomic and autonomous](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Best+Practices%3A+Use+Small%2C+Atomic%2C+Autonomous+Tests) and relying on the clipboard violates this `atomic` best practice therefore you will not be able to [run your Selenium tests in parallel](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Parallel+Tests+-+Best+Practices)

So instead of copying the generated email to the clipboard I would suggest using [WebElement.get_attribute()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) function to obtain the value into a Python variable followed by [WebElement.send_keys()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.send_keys) to type it where required.

```
temp_email = driver.find_element_by_id("mail").get_attribute("value")
```

Also using time.sleep() is a performance anti-pattern, consider using [expected_conditions.number_of_windows_to_be()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.number_of_windows_to_be) function instead